# jQuery Alert Dialog -- Confirm and Cancel

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, alert

I wish to add an alert that pops up upon the selection of the button with id deSelectAll, with the option to confirm, following though on the action, or cancel and return to the page with nothing changing. At present I have the following code.

```
$("#deSelectAll").click ->
    alert "Are you sure you want to remove all"
    root.table.$("tr").removeClass "selected"
```

But all that displays the following result:

[image]

I wish to also have the ability to either confirm or cancel the request. How can this be implemented?

**UPDATE**: I have added the confirm button, but it does not call the alert at all

```
# Deselecting all 
  $("#deSelectAll").click ->
    confirmRemovalFunct()

  confirmRemovalFunct = ->
    confirm("Are you sure you want to remove all locations from campaign")      

    #alert "Are you sure you want to remove all locations from campaign"
    root.table.$("tr").removeClass "selected"

    allLocations = root.table.rows().data() # Then defaults to shows all the locations that are availale

    $('#multi_markers').map ->
      handler = Gmaps.build("Google")
      handler.buildMap
        internal:
          id: "multi_markers"
      , ->
        for aLocation in allLocations
          markers = handler.addMarkers([
            {
              lat: aLocation[9]
              lng: aLocation[10]
            }
          ])
        handler.bounds.extendWith markers
        handler.fitMapToBounds()
        return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the [window.confirm](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp) function. It let you choose between ok and cancel (in most browsers) and returns true or false.

**UPDATE**

You can use it like that

```
if(!confirm("Do you want to continue?")) return;
```

It will exit out of the function if you press cancel.

Comment: How can this be implemented with actions in mind? See updated question

Comment: Do you mean the forms action with action?

Comment: See the updated code, I wish to call the actions seen upon page load, to reset a map

Comment: Pressing cancel with this code doe not cancel the action, it still allows the action. I want the cancel button to cancel the action in the dialog

Comment: You didnt added the if and the return in your code.

Comment: Where is that added? Can you insert into your answer?

Comment: Well in my updated answer there is a codesnippet that you can pretty much copy and paste to you

Comment: I have the confirm at the top of my function, I placed your code there and it returned the error that the if statement was out of place

Comment: Just wrap the confirm you have in your updated code you posted above in a if statement, check for false, and if it is false call return